# startActivity(Intent intent)'s not working in the Android version of my LibGDX project

Tags: android, android-intent, libgdx, start-activity

So I have a platform specific class, which implements an interface from the core object. An instance of this platform specific object is passed into the main activity. So far that seems to be working, but for the life of me I can't figure out where the startActivity()is supposed to come from. I see multiple classes have it, but I don't know which one I'm supposed to inherit from.

Here's my platform specific class:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

public class PlatformObject implements PlatformSpecificImplentationable
{

public void actionviewIntent(String designedIntent)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(designedIntent));
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

I'm trying to make it so it will open the Youtube application to a specific video when the proper URL is passed to the method.

Honestly, I don't really know what I'm doing. If there are any problems I'm going to encounter outside of the immediate scope of this question, I'd like a heads up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Gdx.net.openURI(theYouTubeUri);` which will either open the video in the YouTube app or their browser, depending on their device/defaults/selection.

If you want to use your interface approach, the interface should have a reference to your Activity (AndroidApplication) and use the startActivity from there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with Gdx, so I'd review @nEx.Software's answer for what seems like a solution that makes sense with that library.  If you want to use `startActivity()`, hopefully this can help:

`startActivity()` is a method from the [Context class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29), which Activity extends from.  Two techniques you could consider for starting your intent given your code are...

1. Add `Context` or `Activity` as an argument for your `actionviewIntent` method and invoke startActivity using `context.startActivity(intent)`.
2. Create a method in your Activity class that takes an intent as an argument and calls `startActivity` with it. Make `actionviewIntent` return the intent it creates and implement something in your Activity which will call `actionviewIntent` and your new method to start Activities.

I've had a lot of success with the first technique, I think it's the cleaner of the two, but the second will provide a nice reusable method, if you're doing this a lot for different actions.  Hope this helps!